# Deserialization date collection object (c#)

Tags: json

**Answer format json.Forecast contains the keys in a date format:**

```
  forecast: {,…}
2015-12-08: {nightTemperature: {min: "+2", max: "+4"}, dayTemperature: {min: "+2", max: "+4"}, phenomena: "Ясно",…}
  dateTextDayOfWeek: "завтра"
  dayOfMonth: "8"
  dayTemperature: {min: "+2", max: "+4"}
  falloutIcon: "A2"
  humidityTitle: "75%"
  nightTemperature: {min: "+2", max: "+4"}
  phenomena: "Ясно"
  pressureTitle: "776 мм рт. ст."
  weekend: ""
  wind: {direction: {title: "северо-западный", abbr: {rus: "СЗ", eng: "nw"}}, speed: [5, 7], gustsSpeed: 10,…}
  windDirection: "NW"
2015-12-09: {nightTemperature: {min: "0", max: "-2"}, dayTemperature: {min: "0", max: null},…}
2015-12-10: {nightTemperature: {min: "0", max: "-2"}, dayTemperature: {min: "+2", max: "+4"},…}
2015-12-11: {nightTemperature: {min: "0", max: "+2"}, dayTemperature: {min: "0", max: "+2"},…}
2015-12-12: {nightTemperature: {min: "0", max: null}, dayTemperature: {min: "0", max: "+2"},…}
```

**My classes**

```
public class Forecast
{
    public Day day { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public string dateTextDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public string dayOfMonth { get; set; }
    public DayTemperature dayTemperature { get; set; }
    public string falloutIcon { get; set; }
    public string humidityTitle { get; set; }
    public NightTemperature nightTemperature { get; set; }
    public string phenomena { get; set; }
    public string pressureTitle { get; set; }
    public string weekend { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public string windDirection { get; set; }
}
```

How to introduce the class Forecast to successfully deserialize the collection object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot Deserialaze this Json, it's invalid.
A json of collection of days should look like this:

```
days:[
    { dateTextDayOfWeek : "your date",
    dayOfMonth : "your date",
    dayTemperature :{...},
    falloutIcon : ""
    ....
    },{ dateTextDayOfWeek : "your date",
    dayOfMonth : "your date",
    dayTemperature :{...},
    falloutIcon : ""
    ....
    }
]
```

and so on.
But I don't see any collection in your sample.
your forcast object should look like this:

```
forcast:{
        day:{ dateTextDayOfWeek : "your date",
        dayOfMonth : "your date",
        dayTemperature :{...},
        falloutIcon : ""
        ....
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh , I did not think it would be so difficult . Thanks for the answer , I will convert the json in the correct form .